# Convert negative matrix values to NA in a loop

Tags: r

I have four matrices which contain positive and negative values. Now I would like to convert all negative values for each matrix to NA. The matrices are called `Main_mean, Inn_mean, Isar_mean` and `Danube_mean`.
For a single matrix this would be quite easy:
`Main_mean[Main_mean<=0] <- NA`.
But how should it look like in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the matrix in a list and apply the function to each one using `lapply` :

```
list_obj <- mget(ls(pattern = '_mean$'))
#Or make a list individually
#list_obj <- mget(c('Main_mean', 'Danube_mean', 'Inn_mean', 'Isar_mean'))

result <- lapply(list_obj, function(x) {x[x<=0] <- NA;x})
```

To replace the original objects you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```